# Count the number of trys my VBA took to find numbers that fit paremeters?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I count the number of trys my VBA took to find numbers that fit my paremeters?

In simple terms I have a the code check if a set of random numbers fit some parameters when it doesn't it runs the code again creating a new set of numbers. I would like to know how many sets it gets through to find the rigth numbers.

I have tried static numbers but they dont reset when I run the code manualy again.

Comment: Probably need some sample code. Most people iterate with a `i=i+1`.

Comment: Why do you need the number of attempts, just set the criteria and use the Solver.

Comment: @pgSystemTester the poblem with that is that when the code re-runs itself it resets i leaving me always with 1

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Please [edit] and include the code (or a [mcve]) in your question.